# Using image resources in a jar using maven

Tags: maven, jar, bundle, tango

I have a java/maven project that uses tango icons, so I'm using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freedesktop.tango</groupId>
    <artifactId>tango-icon-theme</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.90</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following code, which would work ok before I moved the proyect to maven:

```
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(org/freedesktop/tango/22x22/actions/address-book-new.png));
```

However, it now results in NullPointerException for some reason.
The generated jar does not contain the images, nor reference them in any way, but classes in other jars are.

I've investigated a lot, but I've found most people bundle their images with their source. This isn't my case.

What do I need to do for maven to reference and/or package these images propertly?
How can I get maven to build a standalone runnable jar (this is a swing application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a slash before the path it works:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/org/freedesktop/tango/22x22/actions/address-book-new.png"));
```

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29):

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. Otherwise,
>   the absolute name is of the following form:
>   modified_package_name/name   Where the modified_package_name is the
>   package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Comment: Thanks, but, as it turns out, this was only *part* of the problem; the images weren't being packaged either, but this was an issue with my pom.xml.