# Image disappeared after converting project to Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxml

I have a small JavaFX app. Everything looked fine, and was working fine. Suddently, I wanted to convert this project to a Maven project (I wanted to add some external dependencies and use them in the app).

In Eclipse I have right-clicked the project, selected `Configure` and then `Convert to Maven project...`. Everything went fine, until I have build and run the application. The whole app is working perfectly, but there was a logo in the app window, and after converting the project to Maven - the image has dissapeared.

I am using JavaFX with FXML and SceneBuilder.

In the `RootLayout.fxml` file, there is an entry:

```
<ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
   <image>
      <Image url="@../../../../../../resources/images/nbtc.jpg" />
   </image>
</ImageView>
```

It is still visible in `SceneBuilder` after conversion to Maven, but it has disappeared from the app after running it.

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Funny thing is, that the programicon32.png is working correctly and it is shown in the application. But it is defined in another place, outside the FXML file:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ...
    this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/programicon32.png"));
    initRootLayout();
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

I have moved the image to the same package where `RootLayout.fxml` is, and have selected the moved image in `SceneBuilder`, the image is showing now, but still, *this is not the droid that i'm looking for*...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using image resources in a jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714028/using-image-resources-in-a-jar-using-maven)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53148244/6395627) may help.

Answer (score 2):

The project folder structure is different to the structure of the classpath at runtime. Assuming the resources are included in the build path properly, the absolute paths of the image and fxml in the classpath at runtime are

```
/images/nbtc.jpg
```

and

```
/com/l4a/mbtc/application/util/RootLayout.fxml
```

Therefore the image needs to be specified as

```xml
<Image url="@../../../../../images/nbtc.jpg" />
```

You also shouldn't rely on the image being available as file at runtime. Usually the resources are included as entry in a `.jar` file; this does not allow access via the `file:` protocol. Use `getResource` instead:

```
this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/programicon32.png").toExternalForm()));
```

Answer (score 1):

By convention maven uses a specific directory structure, that would be best to use also.
(It is configurable, but I never needed to do it, and for someone new to maven it is counter-productive.)

```
src/
    main/                            // For the application code
        java/
             (com/lva/nbc/...')
        resources/
             (images/)
    test/                            // For unit tests
        java/
        resources/
```

In this way the `jar/war/ear` file / class path will contain the paths I put in `(...)`.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/nbct.jpg")
```